# UML use case with Login and Registration

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram

In my UML Use Case diagram I've got 1 actor(User) and 2 use-cases(Login and Registration). They are connected as in image below(Association between User and Login, and Extend between Login and Registration)

[image: My use case diagram in question]

I've read on online sources about UML about the relationships in the use-case diagrams, but I have problem in defining Registration use-case. In which situations can Registration use-case be optional and mandatory?

P.S. Feel free to advise modifications to this diagram.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A use case shows an added value the system under consideration delivers to one of its actors. With that respect, `Login` is no use case at all, since it does not deliver added value. Rather, it is a constraint you can apply to use cases.

`Registration` is not a good naming for a UC. You should stick to predicate/subject[/object]. So `Register for <missing since you did not mention it>` is a good name for that UC. And, now that it is a singular UC, you see that it does not extend anything. The use of extend/include is anyway in most cases a sign of functional decomposition. And UCs are not decomposed as added value is a singularity that can not be divided. Remember the caveat: If your UC diagram looks like a spider web, your design is broken (you tried functional decomposition).

I always recommend to read Bittner/Spence to get a good understanding of synthesizing UCs.

**Addendum:** I said that `Login` is no use case. And that should be true in general. UCs are usually used in a business environment. However, if you also model UCs in the technical environment, you can have `Login` as UC. But UCs in a technical sense are a bit awkward. I always recommend to stay on business level with UCs. I think that's more stringent. In a technical environment you do have other means of describing things.

Comment: I guess that I have maybe a different interpretation of UC diagrams, thinking them of showing a general picture of an information system like IDEF0 top level. So to get it straight:
1. Since I'm modeling an application(an electronic CMR waybill) I shouldn't use *Login* as use-case, even though this model includes a DB of users with details? 2. Is an electronic CMR waybill suitable for a model with minimum of 5 UCs?

Comment: They do NOT show the system, but just it's added value, which is very important. What is a CMR??

Comment: CMR is French acronym for Convention on the Contract for the International Carriage of Goods by Road, an UN convention that relates to various legal issues concerning transportation of cargo by road. I'm trying to model the electronic variant of the waybill based on that convention.

Comment: Then I guess you should end up with at least a dozen of added values. For a Passenger Information System we had some 20-30 UCs. And yes, the login is no UC (except you focus on a pure technical aspect).

Comment: I added a few words about the use of `Login`.